# How to correctly send HTTPS request to Server using auto-generated SSL keys?

Tags: node.js, http, https, request, unirest

I would need some help with `Node.js requests`.
Basically I'm trying to send HTTPS GET requests to a Server which has self-signed certificate.

I'm trying two approaches, `unirest` and `request` modules.
Below functions I'm using:

Request Approach:

```
function sendCommand(command){
    request(IP + command, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
            return body;
        }
        else{
            console.log(command + " was not sent since an error occured!");
        }
    });
}
```

UniRest Approach:

```
function sendRequest(command){
  unirest.get(IP + command)
    .end(function(response) {
      var body = response.body;
      return body;
      done();
    });
}
```

In both cases, I always get `undefined` return value, but Server is online and running, can be easily checked by going to: `https://3.16.143.68:8080`

Since I'm connected to Server in SSH, I can check Server status from there too:

PM2 list Output:

pm2 list
┌────────┬────┬──────┬────────┬───┬─────┬───────────┐
│ Name   │ id │ mode │ status │ ↺ │ cpu │ memory    │
├────────┼────┼──────┼────────┼───┼─────┼───────────┤
│ server │ 0  │ fork │ online │ 0 │ 0%  │ 50.8 MB   │

Of course browser will warn us certificate is not signed but I thought that should't create problems in sending it requests, am I wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node has certificate validation enabled by default.

You can disable it globally by configuring an environment variable:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
request(IP + command, function (error, response, body) {
    // Handle response
});
```

Or you can disable validation when making the request:

```
var opts = {
    url: IP + command,
    agentOptions: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
};
request(opts, function (error, response, body) {
    // Handle response
});
```